# Angular 6 provider Injection error after updating from Http to HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I am having a problem trying to upgrade from Angular Http to HttpClient and I don't know what I am doing wrong....

In main application, my component (**ComponentA**) extends an abstract class (**MyAbstractClass**) that use my lib service (**LibService**). 
This abstract class gets some resources, and after prepares it to be consumed.

When resources has been processed, I call an abstract method that ComponentA implements.

**LibService with Http**

```
@Injectable()
export class LibService {

 constructor(private http: Http) {}

  public getResources(foo) {
      return this.http.get(foo).pipe(map((response) => {
        return response.json()
      }));
  }
 }
```

**LibService with HttpClient**

```
@Injectable()
export class LibService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getResources(foo) {
      return this.http.get(foo).pipe(map((response) => {
        return response
      }));
  }
 }
```

***ComponentA***

```
export class ComponentA extends MyAbstractClass{

    constructor(private serviceA){
        super();
    }


    doSomething(){
        //With my LibService using http everything works and now I can call

        this.serviceA.doAnotherThing();

        //But when LibService is using HttpClient and
        //I try to use this.serviceA, most of the times it is **undefined**,
    }

}
```

**MyAbstractClass**

```
export abstract class MyAbstractClass { 

    contructor(private myLibService: LibService){

        this.myLibService.getResources('myResources').subscribe ((res) => {

            //At this point I have my resources     
            this.doSomething();
        })
    }

    public abstract doSomething();

}
```

What HttpClient is doing that my serviceA is not being injected SOMETIMES? And why it works with Http?

This happens most of the times, so I was thinking that it might be a race condition.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the HttpClientModule injected in your app module?

Comment: are you import like this : `import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http"; `

Comment: In my app.module I have this import `import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient , HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';` and HttpClientModule is in my providers array

Comment: Do you mean that `HttpClientModule` is in the `imports` array? It should not be in the `providers` array.

Comment: Sorry, it´s is in my imports array.

Comment: There is a small issue in your code with ComponentA where super executed you need to pass LibService from super(myLibService);